# Microsoft Office "Read-only" warning not appearing on Samba shares on Mac OS X Server

Tags: samba, mac-osx-server, microsoft-office

some of my users don't get the "read-only" warning (but "read-only" does appear on the title bar and the document is indeed opened read-only) when opening Office 2007 documents already opened by another user. We run the samba share off an XSan volume under Mac OS X 10.5.8 Server. Strict locking is on but oplocks are off (from Server Admin). At home, with a simple samba share in 10.6.3 server, it works correctly. Any ideas? or is this a 10.5.8 behavior?